# Telerik Radgridview for winform row changed event args contains the same value on old and new

Tags: winforms, telerik-grid

Am using Telerik's radgridview for winforms. I am binding the radgridview to a binding list. I am trying to do some validation on this event

```
private void rgView_RowsChanged(object sender, GridViewCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 var changedRowItems = e.NewItems;
 var originalRowItems = e.OldItems
 var changedRow = changedRowItems[0];
 var originalRow = originalRowItems[0];
 var editedUser = ((Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo)changedRow).DataBoundItem
                as myusermodel;
 var noneditedUser = ((Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewRowInfo)originalRow).DataBoundItem
                as myusermodel;
 if(editedUser.MyAttribute1!= noneditedUser.MyAttribute1)// this is always equal even when     changed
 {
     //do something
 }

}
```

Though the event is fired correctly on the change of MyAttribute1, I see that editedUser.MyAttribute1 is equal to noneditedUser.MyAttribute1 . Am I missing something here? Could it be because am using a binding list?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything is fine with your code.
You're assigning the exact same value to the two variables `changedRow` and `originalRow`.
You're then comparing them and they are indeed the same.
I think that you have to use the `EventArgs` passed into the event handler to see which row changed and how.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.! :)- Changed the code here to match what you are saying. My mistake, I do have the right code on my end, I mean original source items only,still shows the same value.

Comment: var originalRow = originalRowItems[0]; is what I have on my IDE. still both old and new has the same value